# How to unplug this stereo receiver ribbon wire to PCB connector?

Tags: pcb, connector

I'm taking apart an old Pioneer stereo amplifier (model 303R). I'm having difficulty unpluging a couple of wire ribbons from the PCB.. I tried pushing, pressing it from the sides, pulling (i thing i damaged the wires when trying to wiggle it while pulling) to no avail... what would be the correct way to disconnect them?
Pictures:
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Why do you assume it is a connector and can be unplugged? That looks like one of those things that just keeps the wires in place while they are being soldered.

Comment: The connector isn't a connector, it's a shield for strain relief for the cable (solder in wires is brittle and has a potential to break if the cable moves)

Comment: @Justme I just asummed, didnt knew better. You were right the wires are soldered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are soldered wire to board connectors. They can't be unplugged. Either unsolder them or cut them.

Comment: I expect Chuck Norris could unplug them...

Comment: Chuck Norris would not need to unplug them, they would just yield.